# Finding intersection of two csv file containing spatial coordinates using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, intersection

I have two CSV file containing spatial coordinates of multi polygons.
ie, The first CSV file contains the coordinates of all polygons which refers a particular crop in a specific time period. And later contains spatial coordinates of the same crop in a different time period.
Now I need to find the region which belongs to both seasons.
I am new in PostGIS. So can anyone suggest me a right direction?

Comment: you should split up your problems in two parts: 

1. Import CSV data to PostGIS,
2. Find Intersections between Layers in PostGIS.

Like this, I'm sure you find many good answers on this site.
... Or use QGIS, which might be easier for you.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, GIS SE is not intended to be a place for methodology tutoring. I would suggest you focus on loading the data, and if you have problems with that, rewrite this question to focus on the problem; if the loading goes fine, and you run into issues with comparison, then come back for that. Either way, the format of the question should be "I've tried *this* using *software components* and ran into *problem*". "I need to"  questions are likely to get a "Well, get to it." response.

Comment: @Vince, can you point out the help section that says questions on this site shouldn't involve methodology?

Comment: @dbaston http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour I beleive in the first section titled `Welcome to Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange` where it states `Asking one, and only one, important question within your Question helps attract prompt and clear Answers.  Your other questions are just as easy to research/ask separately!` and the second section titled `Ask questions, get answers, no distractions` where it states `This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.` will answer your question.

Comment: @dbaston this is also a great resource:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic